# Email to VSO to create stories/bugs/tasks?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a possibility to submit BUG to VSO through email?
I did refer similar post at
[Publish a bug report to Visual Studio Online anonymously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178466/publish-a-bug-report-to-visual-studio-online-anonymously)
but in my case it's not anonymous

Answer (score 2):

Zapier will let you create bugs from new emails. Check out this [Zap](https://zapier.com/app/editor/2110042). For my account, if I email myEmail+newWorkItem@example.com it will create a new bug with the subject as the title and the body as the description.